# How to remove trailing slash in react-router URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I start to use react-router in my application and I am noting that when it has a trailing slash at end of URL (`/url/`) it does not work. I searched more about it, read all documentation and react-router issues and tried to use `<Redirect from='/*/' to="/*" />`, however it was not a good solution, cause it did not work too. So, reading more I found out a suggestion to insert `/?`at end of URL, but it still not worked.

The code of routes.js:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={ProfileFillComponents} />
        <Route path="/seguro-residencia" handler={require('./components/Forms/Residencial/ProfileFill/profileFillComponents')} />
        <Route path="/seguro-residencia/informacoes-pessoais" component={CotationNumber} />
    </Route>
)
```

The code of index.js:

```
render((<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Searching more, I found a guy who made a function to force trailing slash at URLs and I resolved to make the opposite of that, forcing to not have it.

Update routes.js code with function No trailing slash function:

```
export default (
    <Route onEnter={forceTrailingSlash} onChange={forceTrailingSlashOnChange}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={ProfileFillComponents} />
            <Route path="/seguro-residencia" handler={require('./components/Forms/Residencial/ProfileFill/profileFillComponents')} />
            <Route path="/seguro-residencia/informacoes-pessoais" component={CotationNumber} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
)

function forceNoTrailingSlash(nextState, replace) {
  const path = nextState.location.pathname;
  if (path.slice(-1) === '/') {
    replace({
      ...nextState.location,
      pathname: path.slice(1,path.lastIndexOf('/')-1)
    });
  }
}    

function forceNoTrailingSlashOnChange(prevState, nextState, replace) {
  forceNoTrailingSlash(nextState, replace);
}
```

And again this did not work! I need to make this URLs more friendly as possible and I would like that URLs do not have any trailing slash at the end. Any suggestion how can I make this? And why `Redirect` did not work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good option to make this redirect. Below is the code which I am using:

```
   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.path.length > 1 && /\/$/.test(req.path)) {
        var query = req.url.slice(req.path.length)
        res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + query)
      } else {
        next()
      }
    });
```

The explanation is basicly it:

1. In this function, I verify if the URL is grand then one and if it has a trailing slash.
2. If true, I get this URL without trailing slash and make a 301 redirect to this page without the trailing slash.
3. Else, I jump to next method to send a value.

Comment: Oh I was expecting some client side solution. But this should work. But how about maintaining the state of application?

Comment: The state is not involved in this process. It is server-side. Therefore it will not disturb your application. you can pass its routes to URL without trailing slash. Here is just if the client tap on. To make this work in routes you can use 'react-route' and make something like this: `<Route path="/your-url-extension" component={ProfilePage} />`, without use trailing slash. It will not cause any error into your application. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. You're correct. But in my case, I'm using declarative urls and the urls may not be mentioned in the urls (just like in drobox where urls are dynamic as per user creates a new folder). So, it may not work in this case. But I guess, server side is the only good solution.

Answer (score 8):

### React Router v6 solution

RemoveTrailingSlash.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {Navigate, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export const RemoveTrailingSlash = ({...rest}) => {
    const location = useLocation()

    // If the last character of the url is '/'
    if (location.pathname.match('/.*/$')) {
        return <Navigate replace {...rest} to={{
            pathname: location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, ""),
            search: location.search
        }}/>
    } else return null
}
```

AppRoutes.tsx

```
const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <RemoveTrailingSlash/>
            <Routes>
            {/* All your routes go here */}
            </Routes>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! It would be nice if we could get the regex matching to work within the `Route`'s `path` prop (and duplicate this behavior from w/in a `Route`), but I wasn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using the new Routes from v6.4

```
<Route // remove trailing slash
 path="*(/+)"
 loader={({ params }) => redirect(params['*'] || '/')}
/>
```

This basically replaces the route matched with the one without trailing slashes. I would nest it under your main route, so like this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />}>
  <Route // remove trailing slash
   path="*(/+)"
   loader={({ params }) => redirect(params['*'] || '/')}
  />
</Route>
```