# Regex on the url and send the page to correct component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 separate components in react and based on the last parameter of the URL I am sending the page to the respective component.

The issue is if there is a slash(/) at the end of the URL it sends to the other page instead of checking the parameter.

```
example : /abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent

and the other page is
```

/abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent/childComponent.

If there is one extra slash at the end of 
`/abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent/` it sends to the other page. I still want the page to be sent to the maincomponent in this case

How can I fix this?

I want the page to be sent to mainComponent if the URL is

> /abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent/
>
> or /abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent

The code I am trying is :

```
        const segments = location.pathname.split("/");
        const compName = segments[segments.length-1];
        const renderChildView =  collectorName !== "collector" ;
        return renderChildView ? <ChildComponent/> : <MainComponent/>;
```

I have to check if the last parameter is mainComponent with or without slash then send the page to mainComponent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove trailing slash in react-router URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948228/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-in-react-router-urls)

Comment: You have provided an example input. But you have not showed us an example output. So, people who try to answer your question had to guess and speculate on what you really want. Because the question is obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Regex:

```js
const renderChildView = location.pathname.match(/\/?$/) !== null;
return renderChildView ? <ChildComponent/> : <MainComponent/>;
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I have to match the last word in the url if its mainComponent then only I can send that to mainComponent. The issue is if there is one more slash after mainComponent then also I want the mainComponent to be loaded instead of child. So it should work if the 




url is /abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent or /abc/testingcomponent/mainComponent/

Comment: Should not be too hard to update the Regex to fit your needs.